# WPF Columns to matrix

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF DataGrid control with data as in the left image. I am a beginner in WPF and is trying to achieve the right version. I want 'asd/qwe' and 'A/B' to be headers for the rows and columns but they vary in values and numbers and I dont know the names from the start (there may also be a 'C' and a 'zxc').

Is there a way to achieve this?

[image: Concept]

Comment: are a, b row headers ? or just normal cell ?

Comment: Do you need the selection capabilities of a DataGrid? If not, using a nested ItemsControl might be easier. But otherwise, you'd probably have to arrange your data from the code-behind in a format that can easily be displayed by a DataGrid

Comment: I want them to be headers if possible

Comment: @Rachel I would in extent want the 1/0 values  to be changable from this view (perhaps checkboxes). Will look up ItemControls!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be a bit late, and you may have already tried this but the following works for me. Even though there are many loops, it takes care of it in a fast manner.

```
class Program
    {
        private static DataTable Table = new DataTable();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Table.Columns.Add("Col1");
            Table.Columns.Add("Col2");
            Table.Columns.Add("Col3");
            Table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", 1, "asd" });
            Table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", 0, "qwe" });
            Table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", 1, "asd" });
            Table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", 1, "qwe" });
            Table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "C", 2, "qwe" });
            Table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "C", 5, "asd" });

            Gen(Table);
        }


        public class Set
        {
            public string A { get; set; }
            public string B { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }
        }


        public static DataTable Gen(DataTable Tbl)
        {



            // Build objects
            var List = new List<Set>();

            foreach(DataRow Row in Tbl.Rows)
            {

                List.Add(new Set { A = (String)Row["Col1"], B = (String)Row["Col3"],Value = Row["Col2"] });
            }

            var TableBuild = new DataTable();
            TableBuild.Columns.Add("X");

            var DistinctColumnDefiners = List.Select(t => t.B).Distinct();
            var DistinctRowDefiners = List.Select(t => t.A).Distinct();

            for (int i = 0; i < DistinctColumnDefiners.Count(); i++)
            {
                TableBuild.Columns.Add();
                TableBuild.Columns[i + 1].ColumnName = DistinctColumnDefiners.ToArray()[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < DistinctRowDefiners.Count(); i++)
            {
                TableBuild.Rows.Add();
                TableBuild.Rows[i]["X"] = DistinctRowDefiners.ToArray()[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < DistinctRowDefiners.Count(); i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < DistinctColumnDefiners.Count(); k++)
                {

                    TableBuild.Rows[i][DistinctColumnDefiners.ToArray()[k]] = List.Where(t => t.A == (String)TableBuild.Rows[i]["X"] && t.B == (String)DistinctColumnDefiners.ToArray()[k]).Select(f=>f.Value).FirstOrDefault();

                }

            }


                return TableBuild;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ill use this one next time!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up iterating over each 'qwe', 'asd' to add new columns. Then creating an ExpandoObject for each row with 'qwe' etc as properties.

While this probably is not the best way of solving the issue, it resulted in very few lines of code compared to my other attempts.